# Rest service api is throwing Http code 415 error

Tags: java, json, rest, post, http-status-code-415

My Rest Api is as below -

```
@POST
    @Path("/search")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getProducts(@RequestBody MyClass myclass) throws Exception {
        //my code
    }
```

i have added default constructor in MyClass  and all subsequent classes as well .
**Every time i hit the URL with this json(sending in request body ) i am getting The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error , Can anyone help on this** ?
While sending the request i am setting-  Content-Type:application/json and Accept - application/json

Comment: Json i am sending in request body is as follows-                                                                                    {"productPickerSearchRequest": {"planId": "147","categories": [{"categoryId": "2","categoryName": "ANALGESICS"}],"criterias": [{"field": "product","operatorType": "1","value": "string","dataType": "1","operator": "equals"}],"qResultFilter": {"pageIndex": "1","pageSize": "200","bufferSize": "1","newFilter": "true"}}}

Comment: Are you using Postman to send your request?

Comment: Also, please post  here your complete class code and screenshot of how you are sending request

Comment: Please [edit] the question and update it with request body rather than in the comments.